# Is there a Sequential Gaussian Simulation that uses Ordinary Kriging?

Tags: kriging, sequential-monte-carlo

As far as I have read, Sequential Gaussian Simulation always uses Simple Kriging. Is there any chance that it uses Ordinary Kriging?

Comment: You appear to ask two rather different questions--how they might be related is unclear.  Could you edit this post to reveal the *one* question you want addressed?

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry for that, I tried to make a reasoning for my finding.